# phpmyadmin amount of characters per column limited

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm importing csv files, and I can't figure out why I CAN change the amount of characters per column when the number goes down: VARCHAR (50) to VARCHAR (30) is OK, but when I change VARCHAR (30) to VARCHAR (50) it does show up in my phpmyadmin panel, but not on my website.

There seems to be a relation with uploading the csv files, because if column 1 of my first csv-file has 20 characters, and my second csv file has 30 characters in the same column, the website displays only 20. I'm using this code:

ALTER TABLE Library MODIFY titel VARCHAR(50)

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: How is it shown on your website? How are you uploading the CSV file?

Comment: populating selectmenu's. uploading by using 'import' in phpmyadmin. I found a workaround, by starting a 1 row files with extreme long cell-contents, and after I uploaded all my 21 csv files, I deleted that first row. So that works, but it's an alternative.

Comment: You're uploading new data to an existing but empty table, right?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using, please?